WW2 movie where a Russian and German soldiers get stuck with a foreign woman
I've been looking for this for quite a while but sadly even google couldn't help despite my valiant efforts. The premise is quite similar to 2013's Into the White (Rupert Grint), although I'm pretty sure that one came later. 
So I tuned in after a good half of the movie was through so there could be some slight inconsistencies and discrepancies, but basically a German and an older Russian soldier, through a set of unknown circumstances to me, end up with a woman of another origin, with the ongoing war acting as a backdrop. As a result we end up with 3 individuals, each of which haven't a tiniest clue about what the other 2 are saying. Naturally the German and the old cranky Russian don't get along very well given the latter dishes derogatory and provocative remarks most often than not of erhm, politically ideological connotations in the first's address at every opportunity.
So the woman takes care of them and each of them eventually hits the sack with her. Throughout the course of the movie we see all 3 warming up to each other despite the language barrier, and when the cursed war finally ends, the 2 men each go their separates ways. We then flash-forward a few years into the future and the woman had given birth and raised 2 boys who were presumably fathered by the unknown men.

the woman had given birth and raised 2 boys who were presumably fathered by the unknown *men*. That's not how this works. That's not how any of this works.

You're looking for Kukushka (The Cuckoo) from 2002.

September of 1944, a few days before Finland went out of the Second World War. A chained to a rock Finnish sniper-kamikadze Veikko managed to set himself free. Ivan, a captain of the Soviet Army, arrested by the Front Secret Police 'Smersh', has a narrow escape. They are soldiers of the two enemy armies. A Lapp woman Anni gives a shelter to both of them at her farm. For Anni they are not enemies, but just men. 

It revolves around the language barrier between the 3 characters and ends exactly as you described (with her giving birth to their babies). Here's the trailer:




Thank you, Walt. This is such a good movie, and of Russian production nonetheless.
